# How to implement authentication (user/password) to swupdate Web Interface

Tags: swupdate

I need a way to implement some sort of authentication (user/password) to the swupdate web interface, in order to allow firmware updates to authorized users only.
I tried to place an .htaccess file in the root folder of the web interface (namely in the /www directory), but it seems to be ignored.
Anybody has a working example about my requirement ?

And also: In the configuration file swupdate.cfg I found the following parameter:

> global-auth-file

for the embedded webserver, but I don't find which content (and in which format) this file must have.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Create htdigest file using apache's htdigest tool. For example: `htdigest -c .htdigest myrealm someuser`
Then run the swupdate adding the following mongoose arguments `--auth-domain myrealm --global-auth-file /path_to_your_htdigest/.htdigest`.

A full example: `/usr/bin/swupdate -v -H "my_hardware:1.0" -f /etc/swupdate.cfg -w "--auth-domain myrealm --global-auth-file /www/.htdigest" -p 'reboot'`